# CORS with angular.js $resource and ServiceStack Servies

Tags: angularjs, cors, angularjs-resource

i've a servicestack REST Service and a angular.js client. The Web is hosted on an other port then the RESTService.

Retrieving data with $http works but using $resource doesn't work.

in the REST Service I set the following global headers:

```
 GlobalResponseHeaders =
                    {
                    { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" },
                    { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" },
                    { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With"}
                    }
```

Now in angular.js I can read successfully read the methods with the $http for example

```
$http({
        method:'get',
        url:address,
        requesttype:'application/json'
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.ServiceStatus = data;
    });
```

but reading the same address with the $ressource doesn't work
my code for the factory is:

```
myApp.factory('qaServiceStatus', function($resource){
  return $resource('http://localhost:1338/api/status', {}, {
    query: {method:'GET', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, params:{}}

    });
});
```

and i use it this way in the controller

```
$scope.RESTStatus = qaServiceStatus.get({});
```

the error i get is:
Origin `http://localhost:7000` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
and
XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost/api/status`. Origin `http://localhost:7000` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

what am I doing wrong?

I also tried to change the allowed origiin to the exact adress but this doesn't help

Comment: I found out that the problem is the portnumber. (as already posted here somewhere else) But the documentation sais :  If you are using a URL with a port number (e.g. http://example.com:8080/api), it will be respected. so is this a bug?

Comment: Bug or feature, u'll have to ask the angularjs team. Atm they interpreet :post as a variable instead of a port. Solution is to escape the :. Check my answer for an example.

Comment: Sure the only problem is that the documentation doesn't fit the implementation. I'll see wether i can get a statement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the API responding to your client, not allowing your client origin to make a CORS request. 
I dont know what kind of backend you use but you need to review your Access-Control-Allow-Origin settings in order to make it work.

Update:

Bug or feature, u'll have to ask the angularjs team. Atm they interpreet :port as a variable instead of a port.  Solution is to escape the :

Example:

```
$resource('http://localhost:1338\:1338/api/status', {}, {.....
```

Comment: as posted  { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" }, and $http works. if it would have been a cors issue then $http wouldn't have worked also :-)

Comment: My bad not reading properly. Can you post your request from devtools? Both from using $http and $resource. Something must differ

Comment: I just added the reason above, its a escaping problem of the port. but imo the documentation  of the method seems to tell that the port shouldn't be escaped. See my comment on my post.

Comment: Yeah, port bug is the blame here. However, in some cases you might want to delete the pre-flight http requests AngularJS does on CORS with the following code `angular.module('YourApp', []).config(function($httpProvider) { $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true; delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];})`

Comment: this is not a bug, `$resource` accepts using colon for parameters. @JoakimB, you should escape colon with `\\:`